# How to display the properties loaded when the server starts

Tags: spring

Does somebody know how to display the **properties** loaded when the server starts (via some Listener or something like that)?

This is what I have:

1- A file called **project.properties** with configuration parameters.

2- ...which is loaded by Spring with:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="WEB-INF/project.properties" />
```

3- One listener that I suppose could be a proper place to read the properties declared and log them.

```
public class StartListener implements ServletContextListener {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()); 

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        //Here read the properties and do the logging of it
    }
//...   
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciatted.

Answer (score 1):

According to me what you need to do is as and when the server starts you want to log some properties.

To achieve this first of all you need to add the following line in your dispatcher-servlet.xml file.

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

And then use **@PostConstruct** annotation on top of any method you would like to load the properties and log them. You can do this in any controller or service class of your application.

When you do this spring will automatically detect this annotation and whenever it completes loading the application it will call this function and do whatever you have described there.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but finally, I am going to do that in a listener:

```
public class StartListener implements ServletContextListener {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()); 

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ServletContext sc = sce.getServletContext();

        Properties props = new Properties();
        try {
            props.load(sc.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/project.properties"));
            logger.info(props.entrySet().toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("......");
        }
    }

    //...

}
```